# inconsistent object IDs inside multiple vector in C++

Tags: c++

just a beginner here.

i'm trying to store some objects inside a vector, so i can loop it later, but the reference changes afterwards, i'm not sure what happened

the code's below;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Car;

class Garage {
    public:
        vector<Car*> vCar;

};

class Car {
    public:
        short id;
};

int main()
{
   Garage garage;
   short i;

   for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       Car car;
       car.id = i;

       garage.vCar.push_back(&car);
   }

   for(i = 0; i < garage.vCar.size(); i++) {
       cout <<  i << " " << garage.vCar[i]->id << endl;
       // output 9,9,9,..9 instead of 1,2,3,4...10, why is that?
   }


   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're pushing the *address* of a stack-based object into the vector, but that stack based object will be destroyed as soon as it goes out of scope (so as soon as the iteration of the for-loop is complete). When you dereference the pointer later on you're actually reading from the address on the stack where the last object was created, which is why you get the same value every time.

How you fix this is up to you - you could change the vector to store `Car` objects rather than pointers to `Car` objects, you could use smart pointers, etc..

Comment: thanks! i think i'm beginning to understand it now.. and let say i want to destroy, would it possible to just do garage.vCar.clear() ?

Comment: Again it depends how you solved the problem - if you pushed objects directly into the vector then yes (and the vector will automatically clear itself when it's destroyed so you don't even need to call `clear()` yourself unless you want to). If you used smart pointers then they'll also auto-cleanup. But if you allocated your own objects using `new` and pushed those pointers into your vector then you'll need to iterate the vector and `delete` them to free the memory.

Answer (score 4):

```
  vector<Car*> vCar;
```

is a vector that stores pointers to `Car` objects.

```
 for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   Car car;
   car.id = i;

   garage.vCar.push_back(&car);
}
```

Inside the above `for` loop, you create `Car` objects on stack. By the end of the for loop, those objects are out of scope and will be destroyed. Therefore, your pointers inside the vector point to some objects that do not exist. You have **undefined behavior** in your code.

You may store objects directly, which stores copy of the original objects. You can find a [Live Demo](http://ideone.com/OXHM4i) here.

Comment: thank you for the reply! i still get confused with pointers, C++ is so massive!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
class Garage {
    public:
        vector<Car*> vCar;

};
```

To

```
class Garage {
    public:
        vector<Car> vCar;

};
```

And

```
garage.vCar.push_back(&car);
```

To

```
garage.vCar.push_back(car);
```

This will eliminate the undefined behaviour that you are experiencing ( you are taking an address of an item off the stack!)